# VBA issue -- loop starting in the wrong place

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to combine the values of column C, row 2 (tags) to the end of the filled rows to the right with the value in column B, row 2 (names).

[image]

I am able to create a loop that highlights the row of tags I need, but when I create a loop to select each tag individually and combine it with the name value, it starts at row 13 instead of row 2.

Here is my code so far.

```
Sub MakeFullNames()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim WB1 As Workbook, WS4 As Worksheet, Nombres As Range, NewNames As Range
Dim tmpArray() As String, Nombre As String, TagNumber As Long, Tags As Range
Dim Tag As String, LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS4 = WB1.Worksheets("Output_List")
Set Nombres = WS4.Range("B:B")
Set NewNames = WS4.Range("N:N")

With WS4
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Nombre = .Range("B" & i)
        TagNumber = .Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Column
        Set Tags = .Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, TagNumber))
        For j = 1 To TagNumber - 2
            Tag = Tags.Columns(j).Value
            'Debug.Print Tag
        Next j
        
    Next i
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I am not trying to combine the name and tag yet, just trying to figure out why the `For J = 1 to LastRow` loop begins on row 13 instead of row 2
Thanks!

Comment: If you post your code as an image then folks here are much less likely to try to help - we can't test your code without typing it all out, and likewise suggesting fixes also requires re-typing chunks of it.  Copy-paste as text and it's easier for everyone.

Comment: In the first iteration of outer loop, `Nombre = .Range("B" & i)` will give you the name in cell B2, AIT101.  `TagNumber = .Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Column` value is 11 (column K). `Set Tags = .Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, TagNumber))` is a a range from C2 to K2. Then in the first iteration of inner loop `Tag = Tags.Columns(j).Value` should give you the value of C2 (SO1). And to check, `Tags.columns(1).select` should activate cell C2. I wonder how come this code line gives cell C13.

Comment: @findwindow ``Nombre = .Range("B" & i)`` starts on row 2 as it should. This issue is that, in the first iteration of my ``For J = 1 to TageNumber - 2`` loop, the first value returned is the value in C13, whereas it should return the value of C2.
@karma gave a good summary of the issue I'm having

Comment: Every iteration inside of `For j` loop you reset your `Tag` variable, so if you come out of that loop and check the value of `Tag` it will be whatever it was last set to after all of the iterations through the columns in the current row (Column 13's value). That being said, your commented `Debug.print Tag` should list every tag in that row. Does it not?

Comment: @JNevill but OP has a row issue (`i`), not column or is my brain fried looking at this too long?

Comment: @JNevill I have been using the ``Debug.print Tag`` option to check that my code goes through every tag in every row of my document. That's how I noticed the error -- the tags that are returned start at row 13 instead of at row 2 where it should begin

Comment: Put a break point (put cursor on the line and hit F9) on your `Tags=` inside that loop. Run the program, and when it hits the break point and pauses check in the "locals" pane that shows you the current value of variables, and see what the value of `i` is.  Is it "2" when it first breaks?

Comment: @JNevill yes, it's at "2"
When I do put a break point in the ``Debug.Print Tag `` line inside the second loop, the value of ``i`` is also "2" when it breaks and the value of ``Tag`` is SO2. Maybe the ``Debug.Print`` function is just not returning this value, but it is stored in the program during the loop?

Comment: I just mocked up data. Can't replicate. So you are getting bsh on first debug.print?

Comment: @findwindow If I break my code at ``Next j``, debug.print returns SO1, which is what I needed (I accidentally said I needed SO2 in my previous comment).
When I don't break my code, it starts printing at BSH
Is it possible that it is just printing too many values, so debug.print is cutting off the first few?

Comment: Wait, `TagNumber = .Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Column` is 2 here? If so, `For j = 1 To TagNumber - 2` breaks?

Comment: Uhhh lol. Clear your debug window first. Edit: if you are looking at a previous debug.print I am going to be so annoyed lol.

Comment: @findwindow
I clear my debug window every time before I have run this code. I know this is not the issue

Comment: Your excel has voodoo. Spray some garlic and set it on fire.

Comment: Too many meetings today. Checking back now. If the first break point shows that `i=2` then your loop is executing just as expected. No idea why debug.print isn't popping out your tags values. Perhaps because of all the iteration it's clearing older values before you even get a chance to see them? At any rate, I think everytyhing is running as expected and you can finish up whatever code you still need to write without impact.

Comment: Or it's voodoo...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, I decided that it's just an issue with debug.print because I can get the values to appear in other areas!